# Why cant python find Gevent when run under uwsgi via upstart?

Tags: python, uwsgi, upstart

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file       = /home/ubuntu/app/wsgi.py
chdir           = /home/ubuntu/app/
uid             = www-data
gid             = www-data
chown-socket    = www-data
processes       = 4
async           = 100
gevent          = 100
socket          = /run/uwsgi.sock
logto           = /var/log/uwsgi.log
logdate         = true
post-buffering  = 4096
master          = true
die-on-term     = true
logfile-chown   = true
no-site         = true
```

uwsgi.conf:

```
description "uwsgi tiny instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script 
       exec uwsgi /home/ubuntu/app/wsgi.ini
end script

pre-stop script
        rm /run/uwsgi.pid 
end script
```

the error log when i run `sudo service uwsgi start`:

```
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.6 (64bit) on [Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014] ***
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 11 August 2014 23:31:50
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - os: Linux-3.2.0-69-virtual #103-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 2 05:21:29 UTC 2014
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - nodename: ip-10-166-222-26
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - machine: x86_64
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - clock source: unix
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - detected number of CPU cores: 1
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - current working directory: /
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - !!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - your processes number limit is 4592
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - - async cores set to 100 - fd table size: 1024
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - setgid() to 33
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - setuid() to 33
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:09:21)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x23e5ec0
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - python threads support enabled
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - mapped 9560320 bytes (9336 KB) for 400 cores
Mon Dec 22 06:58:20 2014 - *** Operational MODE: preforking+async ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/app/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gevent import monkey
ImportError: No module named gevent
```

Why is this happening? When I run python in the shell and import gevent, everything works.

Comment: check the python version used by uWSGI is the same used by your system python binary

Comment: @roberto yup, they match

Comment: sorry, just noted the -no-site, remove it, it makes no sense in a standard setup

Comment: wow, for some reason that did the trick

Comment: there is nothing strange, no-site is like calling python with -s, that disables the site.py loading. it is used only for special tricks like dynamic virtualenvs.

Comment: @roberto make it an answer and Ill accept it

Answer (score 0):

Command to check uWSGI installed plugin: `uwsgi --plugin-list`

If plugin installed and you get error--> `ImportError: No module named gevent` ,

then install uwsgi : `pip install uwsgi`